# pythonプログラムを実行するユーザーインターフェースについて

Tags: python, html, gui

現在、pythonプログラムを作成しております。現状は、ソースコード上にprint文を埋め込んで、ツール上のコンソールに文字なり数値なりを表示して、値の入力や、変数の状態表示を行っています。

もう少し使い勝手を良くしたい（開発環境を使わずにというか、入っていないパソコンでも使えるようにというか）のですが、GUIなど何らかの方法でpythonのプログラムを実行して（呼び出して）、値の入出力（表示）などをできるようにし動作確認などに生かしたいと思っています。この部分にあまり手間をかけたくないので、どういう方法を選択するのがいちばん簡単でしょうか？

#### 現状について

今調査中なのは、

（１）
[HTML で Python を実行する](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python/python-in-html/)

をやってみましたが、コンソール上で `start index.html` とやってみても、ブラウザ上に真っ白な画面が出てくるだけで、コンソール上はプロンプト表示に戻っています。（特に、エラーも出ていません）

（２）
[Djangoの導入からサーバー起動まで](https://qiita.com/South_/items/416b50a250fc1fe13df7)

もみてみましたが、`python manage.py runserver` のところで、

```
　ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: 
　ファイルにアクセスできません。
```

という状態です。

私が今まで一度もこういう世界に触れたことがないので、今の私には難易度が高いかなと思っています。（htmlを作るにしても、文法から始めないといけない状態です）

#### 実行環境など

##### 言語、モジュール関係

・Python 3.9.7
・Django 4.0.3
・PHP 8.1.4 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2022 09:32:18) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)

##### 開発環境

今の作業ではこのコンソールを使って値を入力したり、プログラムの変数を表示させたりしています。

PyCharm 2021.3.3 (Community Edition)
　Build #PC-213.7172.26, built on March 16, 2022
　Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b1751.46 amd64
　VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
　Windows 10 10.0

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 目的が python で書いたプログラムをデバッグすることなら、今この時点で web server や backend を覚えるってのは超遠回りです。泳ぎ方の練習のためにプールの作り方を学ぶようなもの。将来は web な仕事をしたいということなら今から覚えるのもアリなんでしょうが。

Comment: 「現状は、ソースコード上にprint文を埋め込んで、ツール上のコンソールに文字なり数値なりを表示して、値の入力や、変数の状態表示を行っています。」の目的は何でしょうか？デバッグならpdb、ログ出力ならloggingはどうでしょうか？

Comment: コメントをくださった皆さん、ありがとうございます。「web server や backend 」などの周辺知識がないと簡単にはいかないということですね。htmlでも使って手軽にできれば見栄えも良いかなと思ったのですが、手軽ではなさそうなので、「pdb、logging」辺りを調査してみたいと思います。

Comment: こんなツールがあるようですので調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [django-debug-toolbarでデバッグ効率を上げる方法【Django】](https://hinoapp.com/django-debug-toolbar_usage/), [django-debug-toolbarを導入してデバッグの効率を上げる](https://djangobrothers.com/blogs/django_debug_toolbar/)

Comment: 質問のタイトルは「～について」と曖昧な表現で終わるのではなく、「～したい」のように言い切った表現をした方が伝わりやすいです。 / Python がインストールされていない環境でも (ブラウザ等から) 動作確認のようなことがしたい…と読み取りましたが、合っていますか？

Comment: Django, PHPを実行環境としてあげていることからサーバーサイドと思え, その場合 Web serverとか HTMLは (どういうものであるか)ある程度把握してないと難しいのでは？と思います。もしも単純に Pythonをより容易に動かすだけなら [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)が便利

Answer (score 2, accepted):

標準ライブラリーである [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html) を使ってみてはどうでしょう？

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

message = Label(root, text = 'Hello, World!')
message.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。回答を頂いた後、少し使ってみましたが、なんとかなりそうなので、これでやってみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

> 開発環境を使わずにというか、入っていないパソコンでも使えるようにというか

[Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)を使うのがよいかと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。今回はローカルでやりたかったので、今度別の機会にやってみようと思います。